# Why does my custom HOG detector always draws a rectangle on the center of image and not on the person?

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv, machine-learning, opencv3.0

I have extracted features from hog.compute function and then used those features to train an SVM classifier. I used a script that I found online to separate rho and support vectors from the classified file.

```
tree = ET.parse('svm_data.xml')
root = tree.getroot()
SVs = root.getchildren()[0].getchildren()[-2].getchildren()[0]

rho = float( root.getchildren()[0].getchildren()[-1].getchildren()[0].getchildren()[1].text)
svmvec = [float(x) for x in re.sub( '\s+', ' ', SVs.text).strip().split(' ')]
svmvec.append(-rho)
pickle.dump(svmvec, open("svm.pickle", 'wb'))
```

This code saved the rho and support vectors to a different file which I provided to the hog.DetectMultiScale function. Initially I got the CheckDetectorSize errors, but somehow i dealt with them. But now that it finally executes, why does it always draw a rectangle on the center instead of a person? 
[Check here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3AYX4.jpg)
The final code that uses the file generated from the above code, to draw rectangles on the detected area(s):

```
hog = cv2.HOGDescriptor("hog.xml") svm =
pickle.load(open("svmcoeff.pickle", 'rb'))
hog.setSVMDetector(np.array(svm))

for i in range(1,9): image = cv2.imread('test-'+str(i)+'.png') image =
imutils.resize(image, width=min(300, image.shape[1])) orig =
image.copy()

(rects, weights) = hog.detectMultiScale(image)

for (x, y, w, h) in rects: cv2.rectangle(orig, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), (0, 0, 255),2)

rects = np.array([[x, y, x + w, y + h] for (x, y, w, h) in rects])
pick = non_max_suppression(rects, probs=None,overlapThresh=0.65)

for (xA, yA, xB, yB) in pick: cv2.rectangle(image, (xA, yA), (xB, yB), (0, 255, 0), 2)

cv2.imshow("Before NMS", orig) cv2.imshow("After NMS", image)

key = cv2.waitKey(0) if key == 27: continue
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! You'll get better help, faster, if you follow a couple simple rules when posting a question.  First, use [proper formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) when posting code.  It's easier to read and copy.  Second, it's best to provide a [Minimum, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to illustrate your problem.  That makes it much easier for others to verify and solve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

I can't directly answer your question but I can suggest debugging steps.

First, have you checked what the SVM coefficients look like (the upper code post)? You are making a lot of content dependent operations such as picking the last element in an array, and the text field in there, and text substitution, etc. I don't know the format of your `svm_data.xml` and can't say anything about the correctness of these steps. But you should definitely check the output at every step of this code, and especially `svmvec`. Compare these values to what you get from the original object/method/etc. you produced `svm_data.xml` with - most SVM implementations have methods to access these parameters interactively, e.g. in Matlab or python.

You should correct the formatting of your second code post, which is significant for python code. I guess you're somehow missing line breaks.

Here again first step should be to check the values you read into `svm` and compare to the originals.

Make sure the rectangle parameters returned by HoG detector and those used by cv.rectangle are compatible. Your code looks OK (and checks with online examples). But I would still try drawing a few rectangles manually just to check.

You also do a non-max suppression. Is there a difference before and after? You should first verify that you get something meaningful before. First check HoG detector returns something meaningful in `rects`, something other than a rectangle at the center of the image. If it is not doing that, then your problem is before that point in the process. If the `rects` contain nice rectangles but you don't see them drawn, then your problem is there and should be easy to fix.

If the problem is in `rects`, then you should go back and verify each step beforehand. I already mentioned tracking the SVM parameters from where you generate them up until you set them to HoG detector. Then you can try running the HoG detector with its default person detector to see if you have the whole detection process working.

These are what I can think of at this point.

Comment: Hi, thank you so much for this detailed reply.

OpenCV provides the SVM coefficients of the default people detector trained model. I have compared my SVM coefficients with the default ones and they are very different. Yes, you are right about the interactive methods. I have tried with this piece of code as well that uses these methods provided by OpenCV:
    (rho, alpha, supportVectorIndices) = svm.getDecisionFunction(0)
    supportVectors = svm.getSupportVectors().ravel()
    supportVectors = np.append(supportVectors, -rho)
    pickle.dump(supportVectors, open("svm.pickle", 'wb'))

Comment: Results are somewhat different from the previous XML parsing technique but still different from the original coefficients.

No, The code runs w/o errors, these are just copy paste errors.

Yes, I have manually drawn some rectangles to check the compatibility. There seems to be no issue with that.

Before and After the NMS results are the same since there is always one rectangle in the center. I have checked the values of rects at each step to see if there are other points that are not being drawn but that's not the case.

Btw I figured something wrong with the OpenCV implementation.

Comment: I was using a 96x160 image as an input for hog.compute with a winStride of 64x128. This was a mistake. Cropping 64x128 from the center of each INRIA train image boosted my accuracy on pos and neg Test data (provided by INRIA) to 97.3% and 99.6% respectively. This is a huge improvement, However, the SVM coefficients are still way different than the original ones and the rectangles are still being drawn in the center. So there is something wrong with the coefficients extraction process which I am unable to figure out yet, considering that I am using the built-in methods to find coefficients now.

Comment: So at the end, I would go back to my original suggestion: Try doing it in Matlab (with vlfeat). I too had problems with opencv and couldn't find a way out, and had finally something working with Matlab+vlfeat. Once you have something definitely working, you can try going back to opencv, but this time with a clear and reliable, working reference in your hand. If you have some other problem in your process that you are somehow overlooking, then the Matlab environment is much more transparent and much better documented that you can find your error.